# react-redux how to prevent to show others child category if it's not match the parent id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to show and hide my child element depends on parent id. Assume if user click on parent id -> 1 then it should show all child element of parent id ->1. In my project I have lot of parent category and every parent category have lot of child category. I have an page where I am showing all of my main categories and sub-categories. But the problem if user click on parent category -> 1 then it's showing all child category from others parent category.

here is my redux slicer code:

```
const { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } = require('@reduxjs/toolkit');

const STATUSES = Object.freeze(
    {
        IDLE: 'idle',
        ERROR: 'error',
        LOADING: 'loading'
    }
) 

const initialState = {
    categories: [],
    status: STATUSES.IDLE,


}

export const adsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ads_category",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    
},
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
        .addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.LOADING;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.categories = action.payload;
            
            state.status = STATUSES.IDLE;
        })
        .addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = STATUSES.ERROR;
        });
},
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { ads_category, showcategory} = adsSlice.actions

export default adsSlice.reducer

// Thunks
export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk('ads_category/fetch', async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/ads_category/');
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
});
```

here is my **page.js**

```
const PostAds = () => {
  const [showcat, setShowCat] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const show_data = useSelector(state=>state.ads)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
    
       }, []);
show_sub_category = ()=>{
        setShowCat(true)
       }
  
    return (
      <>
       {/*showing all of my main category */}
       {show_data.categories.map((data)=>(
              <button onClick={show_sub_category}> 
                   {data.main_category}
              </button>  
          
           {showcat &&
                 {/*showing all of my sub category */}
                 {data.sub_cat_bp.map((data)=>({data.sub-category}))}
            
           }
           
             

       ))}
```

here is my api data look like which getting fetching from redux:

```
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "main_category": "Electronic",
        "main_city": "Dhaka",
        "sub_cat_bp": [
            {
                "sub_category": "mobile",
                "sub_city": "Dhanmondi",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "sub_category": "Charger",
                "sub_city": "Dhanmondi",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "sub_category": "Headphone",
                "sub_city": "Lalbagh",
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you map show_data.categories like show_data.categories.map() you should get an id (data.id) of main_category. Store the id of the main category in a state (clickedCategoryId). Inside the map check that clickedCategoryId is equal data.id or not if equal then show data.sub_cat_bp.map((data)=>({data.sub-category}))

The modified code is given below:

```
  const PostAds = () => {
  const [clickedCategoryId, setClickedCategoryId] = useState(null)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const show_data = useSelector(state=>state.ads)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
    
       }, []);
 show_sub_category = (id)=>{
        setClickedCategoryId(id)
       }
  
    return (
      <>
       {/*showing all of my main category */}
       {show_data.categories.map((data)=>(
              <button onClick={()=>show_sub_category(data.id)}> 
                   {data.main_category}
              </button>  
          
           {clickedCategoryId===data.id?
                 {/*showing all of my sub category */}
                 {data.sub_cat_bp.map((data)=>({data.sub-category}))} : null
            
           }
           
       ))}
```

Let me know if it works or not